# json_encode => json_last_error: - Unknown error

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to encode an quite complex array (debug_backtrace()) to json using json_encode and get empty output.

Checking json_last_error gives me integer `8`.
Decoding using [code from manual](http://pl.php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php) gives 'unknown error'.

How can I check what exactly goes wrong?

My PHP:

```
PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.22 (cli) (built: Aug  4 2017 19:40:28)
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
    with XCache v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 2005-2013, by mOo
    with the ionCube PHP Loader (enabled) + Intrusion Protection from ioncube24.com (unconfigured) v10.0.3, Copyright (c) 2002-2017, by ionCube Ltd.
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.3, Copyright (c) 1999-2014, by Zend Technologies
    with XCache Optimizer v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 2005-2013, by mOo
    with XCache Cacher v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 2005-2013, by mOo
    with XCache Coverager v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 2005-2013, by mOo

php -m | grep json
json
```

Comment: 8 is for JSON_ERROR_UNSUPPORTED_TYPE

Comment: check http://php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php for JSON_ERROR_UNSUPPORTED_TYPE

Comment: `debug_backtrace()` returns an array of traces. You could try encoding them one by one and seeing which one fails and manually inspect that one for abnormalities. `json_encode( debug_backtrace()[0] );`, `json_encode( debug_backtrace()[1] );`, `json_encode( debug_backtrace()[2] );`, etc...

Comment: @MonkeyZeus According to http://pl.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php encoded value 'Can be any type except a resource'. On the same page there is an example where an array is being converted to json. Is it just because debug_backtrace is too complex?